# Non-AI Tic-Tac-Toe program

Tags: c++, beginner, game, console, tic-tac-toe

I'm fairly new to C++ and to game programming itself. Today I decided to build a multiplayer Tic Tac Toe program using only elemental C++ syntax/data structures. I also implemented a text interface for the game instead of real graphics.

Any suggestions or tips for the code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define GRID_SIZE 9

using namespace std;

void printGame(char gameGrid[]);
void inputToSlot(char gameGrid[], int slot, char choice);
void initialiseGame(char gameGrid[]);
bool isFull(char gameGrid[]);
bool isEmpty(char input);
bool checkWon(char gameGrid[]);
bool rowWon(char gameGrid[]);
bool columnWon(char gameGrid[]);
bool diagonalWon(char gameGrid[]);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char gameGrid[GRID_SIZE];
    initialiseGame(gameGrid);
    int currentTurn = 0;

    cout << "Tic Tac Toe by Bryan Lean" << endl << endl;
    printGame(gameGrid);
    cout << endl;

    while (!isFull(gameGrid)) {
        int slotChoice;
        currentTurn += 1;
        bool isP2 (currentTurn % 2 == 0);

        // Prompt
        if (isP2) {
            cout << "Player 2 turn..." << endl << "Insert to slot > ";
        } else {
            cout << "Player 1 turn..." << endl << "Insert to slot > ";
        }
        cin >> slotChoice;

        while (!isEmpty(gameGrid[slotChoice])) {
            cout << "Slot occupied. Please select another slot > ";
            cin >> slotChoice;
        }

        // Insert
        if (isP2) {
            gameGrid[slotChoice] = 'o';
        } else {
            gameGrid[slotChoice] = 'x';
        }

        // Print
        printGame(gameGrid);
        cout << endl;

        // Check Winner
        if (checkWon(gameGrid)) {
            if (isP2) {
                cout << "Player 2 won the game.";
            } else {
                cout << "Player 1 won the game.";
            }

            break;
        } 

    }

    if (!checkWon(gameGrid)) {
        cout << "Draw.";
    }


}

void initialiseGame(char gameGrid[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE; ++i) {
        gameGrid[i] = ' ';
    }
}

void printGame(char gameGrid[]) {
    cout << "+---+---+---+" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE; ++i) {
        cout << "| " << gameGrid[i] << " ";
        if ((i+1) % 3 == 0 && i != 0) {
            cout << "|" << endl;
            cout << "+---+---+---+" << endl;
        }
    }
}

void inputToSlot(char gameGrid[], int slot, char choice) {
    gameGrid[slot] = choice;

}

bool isFull(char gameGrid[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE; ++i) {
        if (gameGrid[i] == ' ') {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

bool isEmpty(char input) {
    if (input == ' '){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool checkWon(char gameGrid[]) {
    if (rowWon(gameGrid)) {
        return true;
    } else if (columnWon(gameGrid)) {
        return true;
    } else if (diagonalWon(gameGrid)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

bool rowWon(char gameGrid[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE; i += 3) {
        char firstInRow = gameGrid[i];
        char secondInRow = gameGrid[i + 1];
        char thirdInRow = gameGrid[i + 2];

        if (!isEmpty(firstInRow) && !isEmpty(secondInRow) && !isEmpty(thirdInRow)) {
            if (firstInRow == secondInRow && firstInRow == thirdInRow) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

bool columnWon(char gameGrid[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        char firstInColumn = gameGrid[i];
        char secondInColumn = gameGrid[i + 3];
        char thirdInColumn = gameGrid[i + 6];

        if (!isEmpty(firstInColumn) && !isEmpty(secondInColumn) && !isEmpty(thirdInColumn)) {
            if (firstInColumn == secondInColumn && firstInColumn == thirdInColumn) {
                return true;
            }
        }

    }

    return false;
}

bool diagonalWon(char gameGrid[]) {
    char center = gameGrid[4];
    if (!isEmpty(center) && !isEmpty(gameGrid[0]) && !isEmpty(gameGrid[8])) {
        if (center == gameGrid[0] && center == gameGrid[8]) {
            return true;
        }
    } else if (!isEmpty(center) && !isEmpty(gameGrid[2]) && !isEmpty(gameGrid[6])) {
        if (center == gameGrid[2] && center == gameGrid[6]) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;

}


/************************

 Tic Tac Toe
Text Graphics

 +---+---+---+
 | x | o | x |
 +---+---+---+
 | x | o | x |
 +---+---+---+
 | o | o | x |
 +---+---+---+

*************************/
```

Comment: if (isP2) {
            cout << "Player 2 turn..." << endl << "Insert to slot > ";
        } else {
            cout << "Player 1 turn..." << endl << "Insert to slot > ";
        } can be replaced with ternary, cout << "Player " << isP2 ? "2" : "1" << " turn\nInsert to slot > "; same with checkWon etc

Comment: Oh yeah, totally! C++ can be so beautiful, man. I need to practise more C++ exclusive syntax...

Comment: ternary operator is *not* a C++-exclusive syntax per se... it's used in most C-like languages nowadays, Java, JS & PHP included.

Comment: Ahh~ I started programming using high level language (python), there's a lot of things I have yet to know.

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, all of the languages I enumerated are considered pure high-level languages, since JS & PHP are scripting languages, Java uses VM and C++ is considered high level language due to OOP paradigm, lambdas etc, as opposed to mid/low-level pure C. Furthermore, most code sweetening & syntactic sugar (ternary, Elvis & null-safe operators, lambda syntax, throw-try-catch and so on) you'll encounter will be specific to high-level language domains. Yup, I'm mixing apples with oranges, but note that all of the features are basically replaceable with equivalent low-level code.

Answer (score 18):

Overall, I think it is a pretty good program.

I think I see one bug.  You don't check that the user's input for `slotChoice` is valid.  If the input is outside the range 0..8, the program overruns the array.

Some style and refactoring suggestions, in no particular order...

- I don't like the global `GRID_SIZE` constant.  I would make a `struct` (or a `class`) that holds `gameGrid` and the size.  Then pass a reference to the `struct` (a `const` reference when possible) to the functions that currently have a `gameGrid` parameter.
- Later, if you want to make the program more object-oriented, you can
  make most of the current functions into member functions of the
  class. Since you are new to C++, I would treat that as a separate project.
- Consider putting `currentTurn` in the struct also.
- I think getting the `slotChoice` input and validating it is a good bit of work to move to a new function.  I would move this:

  ```
  cin >> slotChoice;

  while (!isEmpty(gameGrid[slotChoice])) {
      cout << "Slot occupied. Please select another slot > ";
      cin >> slotChoice;
  }
  ```

  plus new code to check that the input is in range, to a new function.
- (Small point) I like to read things in their natural order. I'd rather see the "stuff" for player 1 come before the "stuff" for player 2.  So I'd use a `bool` named `isP1` and rearrange several conditional statements.
- In the "Check Winner" section of the `while` loop, you could save the return value from `checkWon()` in a local `bool` variable.  Then you wouldn't need to call the function again to decide if the game was a draw.
- I see some code duplication, especially in the code that generates output.

  `cout << "Player 2 won the game.";`
  appears again, with only 1 character changed.

  `cout << "+---+---+---+" << endl;` appears twice, and could go in a separate function.
- An alternative for checkWon():

  ```
  bool checkWon(const char gameGrid[]) {
     if (rowWon(gameGrid)) {
         return true;
     }
     if (columnWon(gameGrid)) {
         return true;
     }
     if (diagonalWon(gameGrid)) {
         return true;
     }

     return false;
  }
  ```

  I made the parameter `const`.  I changed the cascading `else if` statements to three independent `if` statements.  I think that reflects the underlying logic a bit better; the three win conditions aren't mutually exclusive.
- You could simplify the logic in function `rowWon()`. If you check `isEmpty(firstInRow)`, you don't need to also check `isEmpty(secondInRow)` and `isEmpty(thirdInRow)`.  (The later comparisons with firstInRow will exclude cases where the other cells in the row are empty.)  `columnWon()` and `diagonalWon()` could get the same simplification.
- There's a lot of code duplication (and conceptual duplication) between `RowWon()`, `columnWon()`, and `diagonalWon()`.  At the core of each is a complicated if statement that examines 3 cells and returns a bool result.  But all of those `if` statements are essentially the same.  That decision could go in a a separate function -- pass it the 3 cell values.  The other part of each function involves deciding which 3 cells to test; those decisions are different for each win condition.

Comment: Thank you so much for the insight! Oh yeah, it definitely need an input guardian for slotChoice, I totally forgot. Some duplication need to be factor out especially for the isEmpty(). I also want to code this using structs and references after I reach that part of my C++ learning (I started programming using Python). And really, thanks for the advice!!

Comment: -1 saying the code is good because it's good for somebody who is a beginner is a not sequitur IMO. either the OP code is good (which it isn't since it basically has 10s of things to improve), or it isn't. btw, calling an objectless C++ code which can be obviously solved in an object domain a "pretty good program" is a severe abuse of words IMO.

Comment: as stated in another answer, "[the code] defines several functions that all refer to the same gameGrid array. This strongly suggests that you could (and **should**!) use a class instead and make those functions member functions of the class. - emphasis mine; saying "Later, if you want to make the program more object-oriented, (...) Since you are new to C++, I would treat that as a separate project." is essentially promoting a structural approach to an OOP problem. Being a beginner is no excuse to write sloppy code.

Comment: @vaxquis: I called it a "pretty good program" because it does a lot of things well. I didn't think it worthwhile to list them, but if I had, there would have been more than the list of improvements I suggested. This is NOT what I would call "sloppy code" (and I've seen lots of that). It is essentially C code with `cin` and `cout`, not full-fledged C++. A very object-oriented approach might be "better", but perhaps not for a programmer **at this experience level**.  The `TicTacToe` class in Edward's answer shows a useful evolution, but it might be too big a leap for someone at the OP's level.

Comment: if you think this code is "pretty good", and you really seen "lots of [worse] code", I can only express my utter pity for the people you have to work with. I've used OOP since I was 14, and I actually learned C++ *before* raw struct & memory alloc C, Pascal and Java... I wouldn't consider learning OOP basics above anyone's "experience level", unless he's < 15 years old.

Comment: and, as a side note, even if somebody *is* younger, I think it'd be just better to begin with a single-paradigm language (LISP or Java) instead. C++ is arguably one of the most complex, branched, elusive and multiplexed languages around - but to see that, you actually have to spend at least 10 years coding in it. It's easy to start with, but very difficult to master.

Answer (score 13):

The code already looks nice. It is easy to understand and well structured. I would change these things:

- You define `GRID_SIZE` as 9. This made me immediately wonder: *Why not 3?*, since Tic Tac Toe is played on a 3 times 3 board. Usually the 'board size' is measured in one dimension only.
- Defining this constant is probably useless, unless you want to switch to other board sizes later.
- But if you define this constant, you should change all the other code so that by just changing this constant you can immediately play on a 9 times 9 board. Currently there are lots of `3` in the code.
- The line `bool isP2 (currentTurn % 2 == 0);` looks unusual. Simple variables are usually initialized using the assigment operator, like this: `bool isP2 = (currentTurn % 2 == 0);`.
- Before checking `isEmpty(gameGrid[slotChoice])` you should make sure that `0 <= slotChoice && slotChoice < GRID_SIZE`. Otherwise you are invoking 'undefined behaviour'.
- You should move the `// Check winner` code out of the `while` loop. The loop should then be `while (!checkWon(gameGrid) && !isFull(gameGrid)) { ... }`.
- In the expression `(i+1) % 3 == 0 && i != 0` you can leave out the `i != 0`, since that can never be true.
- The function `inputToSlot` is defined but not used.
- In the function `isEmpty` you can simply write:

  ```
  bool isEmpty(char input) {
      return input == ' ';
  }
  ```
- In the functions `rowWon`, `columnWon` and `diagonalWon` you don't need to check for `isEmpty(secondInRow)`. It is enough to check `!isEmpty(firstInRow) && secondInRow == firstInRow && thirdInRow == firstInRow`.

Comment: Wow, as for the bool isP2, I don't even know that I have missed the assignment operator and it still works? And I totally forgot about the inputToSlot() function as well, darn.

Comment: -1 for "The code already looks nice. It is easy to understand and well structured."; the improvement list for this code is longer than the code itself, it's easy to understand only because the problem at hand is simple, and the structuring is obviously lousy due to lack of more complex data structures/objects than char array...

Comment: @vaxquis: Although the list of suggestions is long, I still found the code easy to read. The point is: if you are currently in the stage of writing a tic tac toe game, you are still at the very beginning of your programming knowledge. Keeping that in mind, the code could also have been a single `main` function with lots of global variables, deeply nested conditionals and the like. This code is structured into some functions with really good names, and that's a great start for doing a code review and improving the remaining details.

Comment: @RolandIllig just because something can be done *worse*, doesn't mean it's *good*. I find this kind of reasoning a *non sequitur*, my friend. Since OP clearly stated he **has** previous experience in high-level programming, I can only assume he wants to *improve*, not get friendly pats on the back. Besides, since when "having code structured into functions with really good names" is a reason for **OOP code** to be **good** or **nice**? Actually, having excess functions in OOP code, all getting the very same char[] param, is the very first reason the code is flawed.

Answer (score 13):

Here are some things that could help you improve your code.

### Don't abuse `using namespace std`

Putting `using namespace std` at the top of every program is [a bad habit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) that you'd do well to avoid.

### Use `const` variables instead of `#define`

The use of `#define` to define constants in C++ is generally better avoided.  Instead, for example, your code could have used `const size_t GRID_SIZE = 9;`

### Avoid spurious use of `std::endl`

The code uses `std::endl` in a number of places where it's not useful to do so.  Remember that `std::endl` inserts a newline character *and* flushes the stream.  If you don't really need to flush the stream, which is the case for nearly every instance in this program, you should simply use the `\n` character instead.

### Use constants consistently

Your code creates a constant `GRID_SIZE`, which suggests that it might be possible to change it to some other value, but then the `printGrid()` function has a hardcoded `3` which make that not really work.  With just a bit more effort, your code could be modified to accept any size square, or even a rectangular shape if you were interested in that.

### Reconsider the definition of `isEmpty()`

Right now your code has a whole function `isEmpty` which is actually identical in function to `input==' '` which is rather slim for a function.  Further, every instance it's used, it's actually passed a copy of the contents of one of the squares in `gameGrid`.  What would make more sense is to pass in the index value into `isEmpty` and avoid making all of those copies.

### Reconsider the definition of `checkWon()`

Since you already know, based on `isP2`, which player might just have won, it would make your code simpler if you would pass that value to `checkWon()` so that it could avoid checking for empty squares.  All the code really needs to look for in that instance is either an `o` or an `x` value.

### Use objects

Your code defines several functions that all refer to the same `gameGrid` array.  This strongly suggests that you could (and should!) use a class instead and make those functions member functions of the class.

### Hide arbitrary implementation choices

If you use an object, the specific characters used for `x`, `o` and empty should all be private members of the class.  That way, you could arbitrarily change to some other value and calling code would need not know of the change.

### Scrub input data

Right now, you use an inserter to get the value of `slotChoice` but if the user inputs a letter, the code will be stuck in an infinite loop.  Also, you really must add bounds checking to disallow the user putting in some value such as 209581 and altering memory well outside the program space.

### update ...

I refactored your code into a C++ class:

```
class TicTacToe 
{
private:
    // stores the actual square game grid contents
    char *gameGrid;
    // width and total number of squares in the gameGrid
    size_t width, squares; 
    // horizontal bar to print between rows
    std::string hbar;
    // which player's turn is it? (0 or 1) 
    int player;
    // number of free squares remaining on game board
    unsigned freeslots;
    // this contains one character each for player 1, player 2 and empty
    static const char pchar[3];
public:
    // create a square TicTacToe board with width = n
    TicTacToe(size_t n=3);
    // destructor
    ~TicTacToe();
    // reset can be used to play again after object exists
    void reset();
    // inserter for printing board state to ostream
    friend std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &out, const TicTacToe &ttt);
    bool isNotFull() const { return freeslots > 0; }
    // return character representing the player whose turn it is
    char playerTurn() const { return pchar[player]; }
    // return character representing player who just took a turn
    char lastPlayer() const { return pchar[1-player]; }
    // return true if the slot was successfully marked for current player
    bool applyTurn(unsigned slot);
    // return true if the last player just won
    bool winner() const;
};
```

As you can see, the counting of turns has disappeared, replaced by a single private member `player` which keeps track of which player is next to play. You might want to start with this template and see if you can fill in the missing member functions based on the code you've already written.

Comment: Sorry for the input of slotChoice. Yeah, I should have make better use of the #define or implement more flexibility as well, maybe like GRID_SIZE/NUMBER_OF_ROWS?

Comment: I'd define `std::string hbar` once at startup time to contain the horizontal bar, and then print the grid perhaps with nested `for` loops for rows and columns.

Comment: Is there any references to **spurious use of** `std::endl` **is bad ?** I would like to know when I should avoid it and when to use it (when do I really need to flush it ?). Also do I need to use `"\r\n"` on windows ? or just `"\n"` is sufficient. ? Thanks.

Comment: @JaDogg: You only need `"\n"` even on Windows if you open the file in text mode.  The only time you need to flush the stream is when it it's required that everything is actually printed before the next step can proceed.  For example, printing things in a debugging log might use `std::endl` to make sure a program crash doesn't cause some of the log not to be printed.  Another example is a prompt for a question that a human answers.

Answer (score 10):

The others have mentioned many great things, but I'll add some thing that were left out:

- You can shorten the code a bit by defining `main()` at the very bottom, thus you will no longer need that long list of function prototypes.
- Use storage containers instead of C-arrays in C++.  C-arrays can be especially problematic when being passed to functions because  they decay to pointers; the array itself isn't actually passed.  Storage containers are also safer and are more useful because they come with functions.

  For this program, you may use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or, if you have C++11, [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).  There are many resources around on how to use storage containers effectively.
- Instead of using `+=` for 1:

  > ```
  > currentTurn += 1;
  > ```

  just use `++` ([pre or post increment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4706225/1950231)):

  ```
  currentTurn++;
  ```
- A simple conditional like this:

  > ```
  > bool isEmpty(char input) {
  >     if (input == ' '){
  >         return true;
  >     }
  >     return false;
  > }
  > ```

  can be shortened to this:

  ```
  bool isEmpty(char input) {
      return input == ' ';
  }
  ```

  This will still automatically return `true` or `false`.
- Instead of manually filling an array with a loop:

  > ```
  > for (int i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE; ++i) {
  >     gameGrid[i] = ' ';
  > }
  > ```

  use [`std::fill_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n):

  ```
  std::fill_n(gameGrid, GRID_SIZE, ' ');
  ```

  This is part of `<algorithm>` and it works with both C-arrays and certain storage containers that support the appropriate iterators.

Comment: Oh shoots... Python habits. (no ++ operator)

Comment: Nothing wrong with `fill`, but to my eye in this case, I think I'd prefer `std::fill_n(gameGrid, GRID_SIZE, ' ');` for purely aesthetic reasons.

Comment: @Edward: Ah, I didn't catch that one!  Thanks!  I'll add it anyway.

Answer (score 5):

For a better user experience, instead of printing empty spaces in the board, print the number of that square as a placeholder:

```
void initialiseGame(char gameGrid[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE; ++i) {
        gameGrid[i] = '1'+i;
    }
}
```

That would require some corresponding adjustments elsewhere:

```
bool isFull(char gameGrid[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE; ++i) {
        if (gameGrid[i] != 'x' && gameGrid[i] != 'o') {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

bool isEmpty(char input) {
    if (input != 'x' && input != 'o'){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Users will frequently want to play more than one round, so you should ask whether they want to play again.

```
cout<<"Do you want to play again\n";
string s;
cin>>s;
if(s=="yes")
    main();
```

---

When printing output to `cout`, you should consistently terminate the line with `\n`.

Comment: Hi and welcome to CodeReview. When answering questions, please explain your methods and/or reasoning. The point of an answer should be to educate anyone reading it and just posting different code does not do that.

Comment: As Zak said, please explain what changes you've made and why. I can see that your changes were also in certain areas only, so there's no real need to repaste the whole script. You can just add notes on things like why you added `\n` to the end of their `cout` calls and then quote one or two examples from the script.

Comment: I read through your code and saw the changes you did. You did some really good changes, but please write in your answer *what changes you did* rather than *only showing the final result of the changes*.

Comment: I've summarized the main differences in your code as recommendations. This is more of the kind of reviews that we are looking for on this site.